# After 5 occurrences, replace all forward slashes with a hyphen

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL, how can I replace all forward slashes by a hyphen after 5 occurrences of a forward slash like so:

```
https://this/is/a/very/long/url
```

to this :

```
https://this/is/a/very-long-url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.23.1.1.1) with a smart pattern does it:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(url, '(?<=(.*?/){5})(.*?)/', '\1-', 'g');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/97jqtFW1)

`url` can be any string, not necessarily an URL. Every slash (`/`) after the first 5 is replaced with a hyphen (`-`).

The regular expression explained:

`(?<=re)` ... [positive lookbehind](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE) (match only *after* this expression)

`.*?` ... `.` matches any character, `*?` is the non-greedy quantifier "0-n times, as few as possible"

`{5}`  .. quantifier for the preceding atom

`\1` ... in the replacement is a [back reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ESCAPE-SEQUENCES) to the captured match.

`'g'` ... The final parameter 'g' stands for "globally", i.e. replace all matches, not just the first one.

Comment: oh, Postgres allows non-fixed sized positive lookbehinds. didn't know that.